# Unable to get value from input type radio angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to get value from input type radio but i am getting undefined as output.

here is my HTML code :

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options" style="font-size : 20px;padding: 10px">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="inpt" value = "{{option.poll_option_id}}"> {{option.poll_option}}</input>
</div>

<br>

<button ng-disabled="rd" ng-click="pollSubmit()">Submit </button>
```

My angular code is

```
$scope.pollSubmit = function(){
   console.log($scope.inpt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ngRepeat` creates its own child scope. Scopes can look up, not down. You should use a property on your object being iterated over, then check those properties in the controller:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="option.input" value = "{{option.poll_option_id}}"> {{option.poll_option}}</input>
```

And the JS:

```
$scope.pollSubmit = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.options.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.options[i].input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use ng-change and get the value, use the same while submit

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <label class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="y in options">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-change="getselected(y)" ng-value="y.poll_option_id"> {{y.poll_option_id}}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hptix1CP9HOkfjdhvC7A?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Using option input tags need some configuration to make it work.
YOu may use the same `name` attribute to group options that are from the same group. Use a variable in `ng-model` that points to a element in a object from the current scope. `INPUT` is not a container (without closing tag), so any additional text content is after the tag element.

```
 <input name="opt1" type="radio" ng-model="sel.value" value = "{{option.poll_option_id}}"> {{option.poll_option}}
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aavsnc8n/ for an example.

Comment: <input />, not <input> ;-)